# Eigenvectors of a small norm adjustment

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, python, eigenvalues

I have a dataset that is slowly changing, and I need to keep track of eigenvectors/eigenvalues of its covariance matrix.

I've been using `scipy.linalg.eigh`, but it's too expensive, and it doesn't use the fact that I already have a decomposition that's only slightly incorrect.

Can anyone suggest a better approach to deal with this problem?

Comment: How large is your data? Do you need the complete eigensystem, or only some of the largest eigenvalues? Do you need them exactly, or would an approximation do?

Comment: I need complete eigensystem. I found an algorithm for updating inverse of a matrix after small norm update using regression interpretation of inverse of covariance matrix, so I assumed something similar should exist for eigenvectors.

Comment: What do you do with that full eigendecomposition? There might be a better shortcut that does not go through it... And I reiterate cfh's question: "how large"?

Comment: I have 8k features and millions of datapoints, so covariance is approximate. This is to implement [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.07147.pdf) algorithm. Gradient update depends on eigenvalues of certain covariance matrix, and this covariance matrix changes at each step

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A naive approach is to use the eigenvalue solution of your matrix $A(t)$ as the initial guess of an iterative eigensolver for matrix $A(t  + \delta t)$. You might use QR if you need the full spectrum, or the power method otherwise. This isn't an entirely robust approach, however, as the eigenvalues of a matrix aren't necessarily close to a nearly neighboring matrix [(1)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.0482.pdf), especially if its poorly conditioned [(2)](http://wmatem.eis.uva.es/~marsan/publications/preprints/ident3/node7.html).

A subspace tracking method is apparently more useful [(3)](http://www.ee.ucr.edu/~yhua/HuaXiangChenAbedMiao1999.pdf). An excerpt from [(4)](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9789811029134):

> The iterative computation of an extreme (maximal or minimum) eigen
>   pair (eigenvalue and eigenvector) can date back to 1966 [72]. In 1980,
>   Thompson proposed a LMS-type adaptive algorithm for estimating
>   eigenvector, which correspond to the smallest eigenvalue of sample
>   covariance matrix, and provided the adaptive tracking algorithm of the
>   angle/frequency combing with Pisarenko’s harmonic estimator [14].
>   Sarkar et al. [73] used the conjugate gradient algorithm to track the
>   variation of the extreme eigenvector which corresponds to the smallest
>   eigenvalue of the covariance matrix of the slowly changing signal and
>   proved its much faster convergence than Thompson’s LMS-type algorithm.
>   These methods were only used to track single extreme value and
>   eigenvector with limited application, but later they were extended for
>   the eigen-subspace tracking and updating methods. In 1990, Comon and
>   Golub [6] proposed the Lanczos method for tracking the extreme
>   singular value and singular vector, which is a common method designed
>   originally for determining some big and sparse symmetrical eigen
>   problem $Ax = kx$ [74].
>
> [6]: Comon, P., & Golub, G. H. (1990). Tracking a few extreme singular values and vectors in signal processing. In Processing of the IEEE (pp. 1327–1343).
>
> [14]: Thompson, P. A. (1980). An adaptive spectral analysis technique
>   for unbiased frequency
>
> [72]: Bradbury, W. W., & Fletcher, R. (1966).
>   New iterative methods for solutions of the eigenproblem. Numerical
>   Mathematics, 9(9), 259–266.
>
> [73]: Sarkar, T. K., Dianat, S. A., Chen,
>   H., & Brule, J. D. (1986). Adaptive spectral estimation by the
>   conjugate gradient method. IEEE Transactions on Acoustic, Speech, and
>   Signal Processing, 34(2), 272–284.
>
> [74]: Golub, G. H., & Van Load, C. F. (1989). Matrix computation (2nd ed.). Baltimore: The John Hopkins University Press.

I should also mention that solutions to symmetric matrices, such as what you must be solving given your use of `scipy.linalg.eigh`, are somewhat cheap. If you are only interested in a few eigenvalues, you might find speed improvements in your method as well. The Arnoldi method is often used in such situations.

Comment: thanks for the pointer, the QR algorithm seems like a good starting point

Comment: I don't think that the magnitude of the perturbation in the eigenvalues is related to the condition number. This because $A$ has the same eigenvalues as $A+\lambda I$, but a different condition number.

Comment: ps: linalg.eigh on a 4k-by-4k matrix is taking about 20 seconds (it only uses single core for some reason). I need about 0.25 second per update

Answer (score 7):

There exist special techniques for updating the eigen-decomposition of time-dependent covariance matrices. Given a "prior" eigenvalue decomposition (say at some initial time $t^0$), these recursive algorithms lower the complexity of the spectrum update from $\mathcal{O}(N^3)$ (essentially the cost of a new eigendecomposition) to $\mathcal{O}(k N^2)$ where $N$ is the size of your matrix and $k$ is the rank of your update.

Here's a couple of relevant references:

[Adaptive Eigendecomposition of Data Covariance Matrices Based on First-Order Perturbations](http://www.ece.mcgill.ca/~bchamp/Papers/Jounal/IEEE-SP94.pdf) 
 (Champagne, IEEE TSP 42(10) 1994)

[Recursive updating the eigenvalue decomposition of a covariance matrix](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=80968) (Yu, IEEE TSP, 39(5) 1991)

[Online Principal Component Analysis in High Dimension:
Which Algorithm to Choose?](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.03688.pdf) (Cardot and Degras)

[A Stable And Fast Algorithm For Updating The Singular Value Decomposition](http://www.cs.yale.edu/publications/techreports/tr966.pdf) (Gu and Eisenstadt, 1994)

Comment: unfortunately I don't have small rank updates, I have small norm updates of full rank

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov I'm not aware of an efficient algorithm that can handle small-norm full rank updates - best I could find was [this reference](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/680553/), but it does not look very promising. There is of course a large body of literature on eigenvalue perturbation that you may want to look at (see the other answer).